# Trouble creating symlink with semicolon in it from powershell

Tags: powershell, symlink

So i normally use this syntax to create as symbolic link from powershell.

```
PS C:\> cmd /c mklink LinkName TargetFolder
```

However there I'm getting this error when I'm trying to create a symlink with a 
semicolon in it.

```
PS C:\> cmd /c mklink "link;name" "C:\Folder\file;name"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

If I call it from the cmd application it works fine

```
C:\>mklink "link;name" "C:\Folder\file;name"
symbolic link created for link;name <<===>> C:\Folder\file;name
```

Echo args also seems to be working fine when called from cmd via powershell

```
PS C:\> cmd /c echoargs "link;name" "C:\Folder\file;name"
Arg 0 is <link;name>
Arg 1 is <C:\Folder\file;name>
```

So why am I not able to create that symlink from powershell. That syntax works with every other legal character, even unicode. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cmd /c 'mklink "link;name" "C:\Folder\file;name"'
```